# Mi aplicacion corre bien en android 7 y 8 pero cuando la instalo en android 5 me da este error en el logcat y se cierra la app en el dispositivo

Tags: android

> 01-02 17:52:25.778 11942-11942/com.example.osv.rulebeer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.osv.rulebeer, PID: 11942
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.osv.rulebeer/com.example.osv.rulebeer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.osv.rulebeer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.osv.rulebeer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.osv.rulebeer:drawable/fondomadera" (7f06005d)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005d a=-1 r=0x7f06005d}
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2690)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:3791)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:524)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:267)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:263)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:259)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.osv.rulebeer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Comment: Hola Osvaldo.  Por favor agrega el código de tu clase, para que podamos ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: al parecer es un error en el XML linea 2. Muestra los códigos

Comment: En que carpeta del proyecto está `drawable/fondomadera`?

Comment: Creo que el error puede estar en el gradle y que lo tengas configurado para versiones nuevas de android

Answer (score -1):

El problema estaba en `drawable/fondomadera`- lo tenía en la carpeta (v24).

Comment: la zona de respuestas es para dar la solución, no para dar agradecimientos, por favor edítala y explica tu argumento